# Can not connect to Redis

Tags: node.js, laravel, redis

I have Redis, Laravel and Nodejs in my server. Both laravel and Nodejs are not able to connect to Redis as Redis requires AUTH for connection even when i am specifying it. In the REDIS config file I have these two fields which have some values.

```
requirepass aaaaaa
masterauth aaaaaa
```

Could you please point out what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can comment out requirepass if you want to skip auth procedure.

Redis has some security vulnerabilities in its initial setup. You can disable remote access as a starter. `bind 127.0.0.1`

There are some security best practices that you must follow in order to run redis in a secure environment.

Read [this](http://antirez.com/news/96) blog post and official redis security documentation [here](http://redis.io/topics/security).